# Undefined error for file upload if js is included in home page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, jquery-file-upload

I'm using blueimp jquery fileupload in my webpage. I'm including all css and js files in my home page's head tag. I've a left menu which contains many menus. On clicking *menu1* it will send an ajax request and the response will be set in div *menuContent*.

```
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="file_upload_style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery_file_upload.css">
<script src="jquery_ui_widget.js"></script>
<script src="jquery_iframe_transport.js"></script>
<script src="jquery_file_upload.js"></script>
</head>
<div id="menuContent" class="menuContent"></div>
```

The response contains the upload button with corresponding jquery fileupload code.

```
<span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button w3-margin-bottom  ">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
    <span>Upload</span>
    <input id="uploadXLSXFile" type="file" name="files">
</span>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    'use strict';   
    $('#uploadXLSXFile').fileupload({
        add: function(e, data) {
            var uploadErrors = [];
            if (!(/\.(xlsx)$/i).test(data.originalFiles[0].name)) {
                return false;
            }
            data.submit();
        },
        url: "UploadHandler.php", 
        dataType: 'json',
        acceptFileTypes : /(\.|\/)(xlsx)$/i,
        done: function (e, data) {

        }
    }).prop('disabled', !$.support.fileInput)
        .parent().addClass($.support.fileInput ? undefined : 'disabled');   
});

</script>
```

When I click on the menu1 this response will be set to the div but I'm getting error like

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fileupload is not a function

How can I access the js added in homepage in the ajax response too? Can anyone help me to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Append the script to your header like:

```
var s = document.createElement("script");
s.type = "text/javascript";
s.src = "http://somedomain.com/somescript";
$("head").append(s);
```

Or you can use JQuery's getScript()

```
$.getScript( "ajax/test.js", function( data, textStatus, jqxhr ) {
  console.log( data ); // Data returned
  console.log( textStatus ); // Success
  console.log( jqxhr.status ); // 200
  console.log( "Load was performed." );
});
```

Comment: The ajax request calls a php file. So will this work in that case?

Comment: getScript is only for js code but you can use the first approach after uploading the php result